# Set wallpaper on IOS using flutter and wallpapers can also have 3D parallax effect

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, wallpaper

I'm creating a wallpaper application using Flutter containing simple and 3D parallax wallpapers. While doing my research on pub.dev all the wallpaper packages are for Android, how can we set wallpaper on IOS too and what about the 3D parallax effect wallpapers that are set using the mobile sensor?

Comment: There is no api on iOS for apps to set wallpapers. Your app needs to save the image to the photo library and then the user can select it as their wallpaper in device settings.  For the parallax effect to work, the image needs to be the correct size https://www.howtogeek.com/227101/how-to-create-3d-parallax-wallpapers-for-your-iphone-or-ipad/